# Is there a way to add 'live' Event listener for mouseenter event type with pure JS

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, mouseevent

I'm trying to add a live version of event listener in pure JavaScript to monitor a `mouseenter` event in order to execute specific function each time the user enters his mouse on specific element.

Here is what I have, but it's not continuously monitoring the `mouseenter`:

```
const selector = document.querySelector('#selectorId');

if (selector) {
    selector.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        myFunc();

    }, false);
}
```

**the goal is to keep listening to this event even after DOM update**

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is there a way you can attach it higher up the tree, seems a bit of a performance killer to be watching the whole document.

Comment: Did you mean to attach the listener to the element, not the document?

Comment: @epascarello a document is mentioned in generic purpose. There is of course possibility to have limited target area.

Comment: @ggorlen exactly (updated the code part and description)

Comment: OK, what DOM update are you talking about? Some update that removes the listener? If so, please show a [mcve]. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some research I got to conclusion, that using a mutation observer is a way to go.

Here is a solution I'm happy with, for anyone else, who would stack to to same problem:

```
MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;

    const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations, observer) {
        // fired when a mutation occurs
        (function () {
            const selector = document.querySelector('#selectorId');
        
            if (selector) {
                selector.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    alert('bbb');
        
                }, false);
            }
        })();
    });

// define what element should be observed by the observer
// and what types of mutations trigger the callback
observer.observe(document, {
  subtree: true,
  attributes: true
  //...
});
```

thanks to @apsillers for useful trick in the following thread: [Is there a JavaScript / jQuery DOM change listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-javascript-jquery-dom-change-listener/11546242#11546242)

Comment: why not use, window.addEventListener ("mouseenter", e=>......, true); capture phase?